# React js - material ui - transfer list -- using old states

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a react application and trying to recreate this transfer list demo on the material ui - to use the old method of states. but I've fallen into some traps.

current sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-voice-qrym9?file=/src/TransferList.js

https://material-ui.com/components/transfer-list/ -- basing it off the simple list - I am trying to recreate this as a component - to follow on from how the rest of the components have been built - but something in the declaration of the functions and states is causing a ripple effect of errors

my current code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';


import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardHeader from '@material-ui/core/CardHeader';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';


import './TransferList.scss';

class TransferList extends Component {
  
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      checked: [],
      left: [0, 1, 2, 3],
      right: [4, 5, 6, 7]
    };
  }


  not(a, b) {
    //return a.filter((value) => b.indexOf(value) === -1);
  }

  intersection(a, b) {
    //return a.filter((value) => b.indexOf(value) !== -1);
  }

  union(a, b) {
    //return [...a, ...this.not(b, a)];
  }



  numberOfChecked(items) {
    //return this.intersection(this.state.checked, items).length;
  }

  handleToggleAll(items) {
    if (this.numberOfChecked(items) === items.length) {

      this.state = {
        checked: this.not(this.state.checked, items),
      };
    } else {

      this.state = {
        checked: this.union(this.state.checked, items),
      };
    }
  };
  
  handleCheckedRight() {
   const leftChecked = this.intersection(this.state.checked, this.state.left);
    this.state = {
      right: this.state.right.concat(leftChecked),
      left: this.not(this.state.left, leftChecked),
      checked: this.not(this.state.checked, leftChecked),
    };
  };

  handleCheckedLeft() {
   const rightChecked = this.intersection(this.state.checked, this.state.right);

    this.state = {
      right: this.not(this.state.right, rightChecked),
      left: this.state.left.concat(rightChecked),
      checked: this.not(this.state.checked, rightChecked),
    };
  };

 customList(title, items) {
  return (
      <Card>
        <CardHeader
          //className={classes.cardHeader}
          avatar={
            <Checkbox
              onClick={this.handleToggleAll(items)}
              checked={this.numberOfChecked(items) === items.length && items.length !== 0}
              indeterminate={this.numberOfChecked(items) !== items.length && this.numberOfChecked(items) !== 0}
              disabled={items.length === 0}
              inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'all items selected' }}
            />
          }
          title={title}
          subheader={`${this.numberOfChecked(items)}/${items.length} selected`}
        />
        <Divider />
        <List 
          //className={classes.list} 
          dense 
          component="div" 
          role="list"
        >
          
          <ListItem />
        </List>
      </Card>
    );
 }



  render() {



    const leftChecked = this.intersection(this.state.checked, this.state.left);
    const rightChecked = this.intersection(this.state.checked, this.state.right);
/*
    const handleToggle = (value) => () => {
      const currentIndex = checked.indexOf(value);
      const newChecked = [...checked];

      if (currentIndex === -1) {
        newChecked.push(value);
      } else {
        newChecked.splice(currentIndex, 1);
      }

      setChecked(newChecked);
    };

    const numberOfChecked = (items) => this.intersection(checked, items).length;

    const handleToggleAll = (items) => () => {
      if (numberOfChecked(items) === items.length) {
        setChecked(not(checked, items));
      } else {
        setChecked(union(checked, items));
      }
    };

    const handleCheckedRight = () => {
      setRight(right.concat(leftChecked));
      setLeft(not(left, leftChecked));
      setChecked(not(checked, leftChecked));
    };

    const handleCheckedLeft = () => {
      setLeft(left.concat(rightChecked));
      setRight(not(right, rightChecked));
      setChecked(not(checked, rightChecked));
    };

    const customList = (title, items) => (
      <Card>
        <CardHeader
          className={classes.cardHeader}
          avatar={
            <Checkbox
              onClick={handleToggleAll(items)}
              checked={numberOfChecked(items) === items.length && items.length !== 0}
              indeterminate={numberOfChecked(items) !== items.length && numberOfChecked(items) !== 0}
              disabled={items.length === 0}
              inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'all items selected' }}
            />
          }
          title={title}
          subheader={`${numberOfChecked(items)}/${items.length} selected`}
        />
        <Divider />
        <List className={classes.list} dense component="div" role="list">
          {items.map((value) => {
            const labelId = `transfer-list-all-item-${value}-label`;

            return (
              <ListItem key={value} role="listitem" button onClick={handleToggle(value)}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <Checkbox
                    checked={checked.indexOf(value) !== -1}
                    tabIndex={-1}
                    disableRipple
                    inputProps={{ 'aria-labelledby': labelId }}
                  />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText id={labelId} primary={`List item ${value + 1}`} />
              </ListItem>
            );
          })}
          <ListItem />
        </List>
      </Card>
    );

*/


    return (
      <Grid container spacing={2} justify="center" alignItems="center">
        <Grid item>{this.customList('Choices', this.state.left)}</Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <Grid container direction="column" alignItems="center">
            <Button
              variant="outlined"
              size="small"
              //className={classes.button}
              onClick={this.handleCheckedRight}
              disabled={leftChecked.length === 0}
              aria-label="move selected right"
            >
              &gt;
            </Button>
            <Button
              variant="outlined"
              size="small"
              //className={classes.button}
              onClick={this.handleCheckedLeft}
              disabled={rightChecked.length === 0}
              aria-label="move selected left"
            >
              &lt;
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>{this.customList('Chosen', this.state.right)}</Grid>
      </Grid>
    )
  }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return bindActionCreators({  }, dispatch);
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TransferList))



////////

/*

export default function TransferList() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState([]);
  const [left, setLeft] = React.useState([0, 1, 2, 3]);
  const [right, setRight] = React.useState([4, 5, 6, 7]);

  const leftChecked = intersection(checked, left);
  const rightChecked = intersection(checked, right);

  const handleToggle = (value) => () => {
    const currentIndex = checked.indexOf(value);
    const newChecked = [...checked];

    if (currentIndex === -1) {
      newChecked.push(value);
    } else {
      newChecked.splice(currentIndex, 1);
    }

    setChecked(newChecked);
  };

  const numberOfChecked = (items) => intersection(checked, items).length;

  const handleToggleAll = (items) => () => {
    if (numberOfChecked(items) === items.length) {
      setChecked(not(checked, items));
    } else {
      setChecked(union(checked, items));
    }
  };

  const handleCheckedRight = () => {
    setRight(right.concat(leftChecked));
    setLeft(not(left, leftChecked));
    setChecked(not(checked, leftChecked));
  };

  const handleCheckedLeft = () => {
    setLeft(left.concat(rightChecked));
    setRight(not(right, rightChecked));
    setChecked(not(checked, rightChecked));
  };

  const customList = (title, items) => (
    <Card>
      <CardHeader
        className={classes.cardHeader}
        avatar={
          <Checkbox
            onClick={handleToggleAll(items)}
            checked={numberOfChecked(items) === items.length && items.length !== 0}
            indeterminate={numberOfChecked(items) !== items.length && numberOfChecked(items) !== 0}
            disabled={items.length === 0}
            inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'all items selected' }}
          />
        }
        title={title}
        subheader={`${numberOfChecked(items)}/${items.length} selected`}
      />
      <Divider />
      <List className={classes.list} dense component="div" role="list">
        {items.map((value) => {
          const labelId = `transfer-list-all-item-${value}-label`;

          return (
            <ListItem key={value} role="listitem" button onClick={handleToggle(value)}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Checkbox
                  checked={checked.indexOf(value) !== -1}
                  tabIndex={-1}
                  disableRipple
                  inputProps={{ 'aria-labelledby': labelId }}
                />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText id={labelId} primary={`List item ${value + 1}`} />
            </ListItem>
          );
        })}
        <ListItem />
      </List>
    </Card>
  );


*/

//////////
```

latest sandbox working
https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-voice-qrym9?file=/src/TransferList.js

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the entire answer but in customList():

```
onClick={this.handleToggleAll(items)}
```

calls the method rather than sets it as an event handler, you probably want:

```
onClick={() => this.handleToggleAll(items)}
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-voice-qrym9?file=/src/TransferList.js -- I've managed to display the checkboxes - but clicking on them has no impact?

Comment: Where you have this.state = { *stuff here* } I expect that you want this.setState({ *stuff here* }) (except for the constructor). Edit: from the looks of your codesandbox link it appears to be putting a yellow squiggle under the places where it thinks this is an issue.

Comment: good spot - ok ok - we are close now -- the checkboxes check - but I can't seem to get anything to work on the transfer left/right buttons - https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-voice-qrym9?file=/src/TransferList.js

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-voice-qrym9?file=/src/TransferList.js -- got it working - thanks man -- how could we improve this -- compact it more

Comment: A lot of what I would do is probably pretty subjective, but I'll mention a couple of things: I would probably remove the not, intersection and union function to somewhere outside of the class definition - they feel like general utility functions that aren't specific to the class; I would probably factorise the left and right functions (e.g. handleCheckedLeft) as they do the same thing just on different lists; in customList I would probably look to calculate this.numberOfChecked(items) once (before the return statement). I'm certainly not an expert at this stuff though.